# Symfony 4 autowire DataTransformerInterface

Tags: symfony

I want to build a new form type to handle one of my problem.

But, using this code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

/**
 * Entity hidden custom type class definition
 */
class EntityHiddenType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var DataTransformerInterface $transformer
     */
    private $transformer;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param DataTransformerInterface $transformer
     */
    public function __construct(DataTransformerInterface $transformer)
    {
        $this->transformer = $transformer;
    }
```

I got this error :

> Cannot autowire service "App\Form\Type\EntityHiddenType": argument
>   "$transformer" of method "__construct()" references interface
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface" but no such service
>   exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

I tried to put autowire to off, but I can't inject an interface right ?

Why I can't autowire this Symfony interface ?

Comment: Keep autowire to true. Did you run debug:container command to fetch available services ? No problem with other dependencies injection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your DataTransformer in a own class (which implements `DataTransformerInterface`) you have to inject this class (your implementation) - not the interface.

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer

you could of course aliasing the interface for your specific implementation - but then you only could have this one DataTransformer when injecting the Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Because DataTransformerInterface is not autowirable.

Try this, to see autowiring classes/interfaces

```
bin/console debug:autowiring
```

The only way to make it work is to create a service class which implements DataTransformerInterface

Inject your new service by configuring it in service.yml

Comment: technically correct - but unhelpful in this specific case.